# NSTimer missing fire date when clock is manually set forward

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am setting up a timer to run a specific function in the future like this:

```
pingTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:pingAtDate
                                     interval:0
                                       target:self
                                     selector:@selector(ping:)
                                     userInfo:nil
                                      repeats:NO];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:pingTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

The date is approximately 1 week in the future, so for testing purposes I (and others) have been setting the system clock forward 8 days to ensure that the specified event happens.  The problem is that it doesn't happen.

When scheduling a few minutes in the future I have observed that the timer still does go off, but it appears to go off after a specific number of minutes.  Say I schedule the timer for a date 5 minutes in the future, then I set the clock forward 1 hour, the timer does actually fire 5 minutes later, but since I set the clock forward 1 hour the time that it fires at no longer aligns with the time that it was scheduled to fire at.

This is not what I would expect to happen, as I am calling "initWithFireDate".

Although all of this seems wrong to me (and may be an interesting observation to others) the question is how do I ensure that the timer fires as soon as it notices that it's fire date is in the past (i.e. How do I ensure that my timer will fire when somebody moves the clock past the scheduled firing date).

Comment: An `NSTimer` is not a wall-clock-time mechanism; you should not expect it to be reliable across a week. See [Schedule multiple daily events with NSTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2632996) and [Is there an absolutely certain way to have a long term NSTimer fire?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8449351)

Comment: Is your run loop actually processing events in the time before the timer fires? I could imagine that if the timer is the only source on the run loop (or at least, the only source that actually ever has an event), then the run loop won't notice that the wall clock changed. But this is pure speculation.

Comment: @JoshCaswell that isn't really the issue, the issue being that if you set a timer to 1 minute in the future, then set your system clock to 2 minutes in the future, it will still fire in one minute.

Comment: You could try listening for the `NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification` notification and poking the fire date of your timer.

Comment: I am working on the same problem with the OP and the run loop is running

Comment: @KevinBallard we may use that as a work around, we have discussed it, but it is still strange behavior... if you ask the runloop for `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] limitDateForMode:@"kCFRunLoopDefaultMode"]` it will give you the date in the past `[NSDate date]` will give the modified system clock date at that time

Comment: Yeah, you have to listen for the clock to change and reset your timer.  Or use local notifications instead.

Comment: @GradyPlayer, exactly; `NSTimer` doesn't know and doesn't care what the real world, or your iPhone thinks the hour of the day is. It's a mechanism for making things happen in _computer_ time.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I would absolutely expect it to say... hey this timer is in the past: fire!... they are doing something to prevent that.

Comment: That's simply not what an `NSTimer` is for, @GradyPlayer; you need to write a higher-level mechanism to deal with "real" time. The simplest way to demonstrate this is to set a timer then sleep the computer. The sleep time doesn't count for the timer.

Comment: *Just putting this in other words what others have mentionned:*

Dealing with `NSTimer` is like telling someone to count to some number. *Count to ten.*  Counting to ten is irrelevant to what the time actually is.  `NSTimer` doesn't mark the calendar ten seconds in the future... that would be *scheduling*.

`NSTimer` simply counts the time that *actually* ellapses.

Comment: Once again, consider using local notifications.

Comment: @HotLicks Unless I seriously misunderstand Local Notifications (which is possible), they aren't suitable.  I am not trying notify the user of something at some date in the future (i.e. have something delivered to the notification center), I am trying to schedule the program to do some internal house keeping at some date in the future.  If you can use local notifications for this, perhaps you can point me to an example?  This is what I assume you mean by local notifications:  http://www.renssies.nl/2012/02/mountain-lion-the-new-notifications-center/.

Comment: AppDelegate `didReceiveLocalNotification` is called when a local notification expires.  That (and some logic in `applicationWillTerminate` and maybe `applicationWillResignActive` and/or `applicationWillEnterBackground` to clean things up) should be all that you need.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There were some good comments left, but no complete answers.  I am going to pull all the pertinent details together here.

An NSTimer is not a clock-time mechanism.  When you set a "FireDate" you cannot be sure that the timer will actually fire at that date.  You are actually telling the timer to run for specific amount of time before firing.  That amount of time is the difference between when you add the timer to the run loop, and the date that you scheduled the timer to fire at.

If your system goes to sleep (or your application is suspended), your timer is no longer ticking down.  It will resume ticking down when your system wakes up (or your application becomes active), but this means that your timer will now NOT execute at the original "FireDate".  Rather it will execute at the "FireDate" + (amount of time your computer was asleep).

Similarly if a user changes the system time, this does not affect the timer in any way.  If the timer was scheduled to fire at a date 8 hours in the future, it will continue ticking down 8 hours worth of time before it fires.

In the case where you want a timer to fire at a specific clock time in the distant future, you will need to make sure your application is notified of the following events:

1. Wake from sleep
2. System time change

When any of these events occur you will need to invalidate and adjust any existing timers.

```
/* If the clock time changed or we woke from sleep whe have to reset these long term timers */
- (void) resetTimers: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    //Invalidate and Reset long term NSTimers
}
```

You can observe the following notifications to be notified when those events are going to happen.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                          
                                         selector:@selector(resetTimers:)               
                                             name:NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification            
                                           object:nil];

[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self
                                                       selector:@selector(resetTimers:)         
                                                           name:NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification
                                                         object:nil];
```

Comment: Nice summary! You may also want to take a look at [Run code at a certain time according to the system clock](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11404348). Although it's focused on OS X, you might find it useful.

Comment: @JoshCaswell -- That is an excellent and very pertinent post.  I wish I had found it when I first ran into this issue.