# NSTimer fires before the firedate

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have the below code that initializes a NSTimer based on the value stored in NSDefault variable `checkOutTime`.

Suppose if I change the time in this variable to a past time (before the current time) and reinitialize the timer it fires automatically and calls the `ForceCheckOut()` callback method.

I need the timer to fire only at the fire date given.

```
func InitilizeAutoCheckOut(isExtendedCheckout:Bool)
{

        let checkOutTime = self.defaults.valueForKey("checkOutTime") as! String

        print(checkOutTime)



        if !checkOutTime.isEmpty
        {
            let date = self.StringToDate(checkOutTime, IsExtendedCheckout: isExtendedCheckout)

            print(date)

            let autoCheckOutTimer = NSTimer(fireDate: date, interval: 24*60*60, target: self, selector: #selector(DashboardViewController.ForceCheckOut), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(autoCheckOutTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

        }

}
```

Comment: Check timezone of fire date is system timezone or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in a couple of places ([here is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574532/nstimer-missing-fire-date-when-clock-is-manually-set-forward)), `NSTimer`'s `fireDate` isn't actually a calendar datetime at which the timer fires. It's more accurate to think of it as a mechanism to ask for a countdown. Notably, `NSTimer` doesn't account for clock resets, backgrounding, etc. It basically calculates a number until it's supposed to fire, decrements that number periodically, and fires once that number <= 0. Changing the local clock doesn't affect that number, and suspending the process (e.g., by backgrounding the app) will cause the countdown to resume from its current value without accounting for the time it spent asleep. That's arguably nonintuitive, since the `fireDate` strongly implies a contract of "fire on this calendar date", but the API is what it is.

With that knowledge, you can intuit that the behavior you're seeing is expected: If you set a date in the past, you're essentially asking the timer to count down from (negative number), so the timer immediately recognizes it's fire condition is met (remaining time <= 0), and fires as soon as it's woken by the runloop.

But even without that knowledge, I would argue the behavior meets more expectations than it defies. Consider:

> The system reserves the right to apply a small amount of tolerance to certain timers regardless of the value of [tolerance]. -- [NSTimer class ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-SW10).

If you schedule a timer for a very brief time in the future, the timer may not get checked by the runloop until after its scheduled time has actually passed. By firing the timer even though the time is in the past, the timer fires more or less at the specified time, and thus meets the programmer's expectation.

In addition, your desired behavior would introduce a whole set of complications around managing timers. What if you create a timer with a fire date in the future, but don't add it until that fire date has past? Should the timer fire or not? The current behavior obviates that decision.

The simplest solution for you is probably to check the fire date before you schedule the timer, and only adding it to the run loop if the fire date meets your conditions:

```
let date = self.StringToDate(checkOutTime, IsExtendedCheckout: isExtendedCheckout)
let comparison = date.compare(NSDate())
guard comparison != .OrderedAscending else {
    print("date \(date) has already passed. Not scheduling timer.")
    return
}
```