# Does NSTimer works in conjunction with device's clock?

Tags: ios, nstimer

If we manually change the clock time of device, will the NSTimer output change? I want to show a count down, but I am not sure if user will change the device in-between then will it change the NSTimer outcome too ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSTimer missing fire date when clock is manually set forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574532/nstimer-missing-fire-date-when-clock-is-manually-set-forward). Not an exact duplicate, but it contains the answer to your question.

Comment: @Rengers Kindly go through the question that you mentioned. My question is not at all duplicate. Better just highlight that I may find my answer under that question instead of accusing.

Comment: I wasn't accusing you of anything. Like I said, not an exact duplicate question, but the answer I linked does contain the info you want. It says: "If a user changes the system time, this does not affect the timer in any way.". So I think that is the information you are looking for.